# The Jenkins Test Result Analyzer does NOT list the test functions according to their execution order

Tags: jenkins, pytest

I use the Jenkins Test Result Analyzer for pytest repots in jenkins with the command:

```
pytest --junitxml=results.xml
```

In the report the funcitons are listed alphabetically. Is it possible to configure the analyzer so that the functions are listed according to their **execution order**?